# Non-type variadic template parameter

Tags: c++, c++17, variadic-templates

I want to make class with variadic wchar* value arguments. Consider the following example.

```
template<const wchar_t* ...properties>
class my_iterator{
public:
     std::tuple<std::wstring...> get(); // quantity of wstrings depend on quantity of template parameters
};
```

I want to use that like the following

```
my_iterator<L"hello", L"world"> inst(object_collection);
while(inst.next()){
    auto x = inst.get();
}
```

But I receive compile error, when I instantiate the class.

> error C2762: 'my_iterator': invalid expression as a template argument for
>   'properties'

What's wrong and what to do?

Comment: what is 'test'? Is this really the error from the code you show here?

Comment: also `while(inst)`, how is this supposed to compile? probably not related to the actual problem, but still distracting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's wrong is [[temp.arg.nontype] §2.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#2.3). String literals cannot (currently) be used as template arguments. What you could do, for example, is declare named array objects and use those as arguments:

```
template<const wchar_t* ...properties>
class my_iterator {};


int main()
{
    static constexpr const wchar_t a[] = L"hello";
    static constexpr const wchar_t b[] = L"world";

    my_iterator<a, b> inst;
}
```

working example [here](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%0A%0Atemplate%3Cconst+wchar_t*+...properties%3E%0Aclass+my_iterator+%7B%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++static+constexpr+const+wchar_t+a%5B%5D+%3D+L%22hello%22%3B%0A++++static+constexpr+const+wchar_t+b%5B%5D+%3D+L%22world%22%3B%0A%0A++++my_iterator%3Ca,+b%3E+inst%3B%0A%7D%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:55.359173878387125,l:'4',m:67.91383219954649,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:32.08616780045352,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:60.93994778067885,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'0'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B17+-O3+-stdlib%3Dlibc%2B%2B',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:39.06005221932115,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4)

Comment: Literally did this last week for the same reason. Was a bit annoying. Fortunately shortly thereafter discovered my whole approach was stupid and was able to delete it all, but still... ;)

Comment: Yeah, personally I would just try to keep strings out of my template stuffs. But if you must, the above would seem to be the simplest solution for the particular problem at the moment. And it's kinda forward-compatible, assuming we will eventually be able to pass string literals as template arguments…

Comment: Yep, agreed. :)

Comment: Note, that template will be parametrized by pointers, i.e. their addresses, and not their contents. So if you write the same code in different function (i.e. using different instances of `a` and `b`) you'll get different template instantiation.

Answer (score 3):

This has nothing to do with the template parameter being *variadic* or *non-type* - string literals cannot simply be used as template parameters (until [P0732](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0732r0.pdf) - which was accepted - becomes reality).

```
template <const char*> struct foo { };
foo<"hi"> x;
```

Will fail as well. [**live example on godbolt.org**](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/FonH12)

> error: '"hi"' is not a valid template argument for type 'const char*' because string literals can never be used in this context

Comment: I read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters#Non-type_template_parameter  and pointer to object _can_ be template argument. Why not?

Comment: @AlexeySubbota `"hi"` is not of a type `const char*`. It's `const char[3]`, **which is not the same**

Comment: Even with P0732 string literals cannot be used with a `const char*` template parameter, you will have to use your own type.

Comment: Seems a bit of a pain not to actually include P0732's sample implementation in the library. It looks decent

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to pass the characters one by one,

```
#include <tuple>

template<wchar_t ...properties>
class my_iterator{
public:
     std::tuple<decltype(properties)...> get(); // quantity of wstrings depend on quantity of template parameters
};

my_iterator<L'h', L'e',  L'l', L'l', L'o'> inst;
```